# How to avoid character wrap of text in TextView, for auto-resizing text?

Tags: android, textview, autoresize

### Background

After a lot of searching for the best solution of auto-resizing TextView (according to content, size, min&max lines, and font-size restrictions), I've made a merged solution for it all, [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView).

NOTE: I don't use other solutions because they don't work well, each has its own issues (something isn't supported, text goes outside of TextView, text get truncated,...) .

Demonstration of it works:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView/master/animationPreview.gif

### The problem

On some cases, the last character of one line wraps to the next line, as such:

[image]

Green is the boundaries of the TextView, red is outside of it.

### The code

Basically, given the size of the TextView, its min&max font size and min&max lines, and the content (text) that's supposed to be within, it finds (using binary search) what font size should fit within the boundaries of the TextView.

The code is available in Github already, but here it is just in case :

```
public class AutoResizeTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;
    private final RectF _availableSpaceRect = new RectF();
    private final SizeTester _sizeTester;
    private float _maxTextSize, _spacingMult = 1.0f, _spacingAdd = 0.0f, _minTextSize;
    private int _widthLimit, _maxLines;
    private boolean _initialized = false;
    private TextPaint _paint;

    private interface SizeTester {
        /**
         * @param suggestedSize  Size of text to be tested
         * @param availableSpace available space in which text must fit
         * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
         * text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
         * otherwise
         */
        int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
    }

    public AutoResizeTextView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    public AutoResizeTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    public AutoResizeTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // using the minimal recommended font size
        _minTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        _maxTextSize = getTextSize();
        _paint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
        if (_maxLines == 0)
            // no value was assigned during construction
            _maxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        // prepare size tester:
        _sizeTester = new SizeTester() {
            final RectF textRect = new RectF();

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public int onTestSize(final int suggestedSize, final RectF availableSPace) {
                _paint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);
                final TransformationMethod transformationMethod = getTransformationMethod();
                final String text;
                if (transformationMethod != null)
                    text = transformationMethod.getTransformation(getText(), AutoResizeTextView.this).toString();
                else
                    text = getText().toString();

                final boolean singleLine = getMaxLines() == 1;
                if (singleLine) {
                    textRect.bottom = _paint.getFontSpacing();
                    textRect.right = _paint.measureText(text);
                } else {
                    final StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, _paint, _widthLimit, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, _spacingMult, _spacingAdd, true);
                    // return early if we have more lines
                    if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines())
                        return 1;
                    textRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();
                    int maxWidth = -1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++)
                        if (maxWidth < layout.getLineRight(i) - layout.getLineLeft(i))
                            maxWidth = (int) layout.getLineRight(i) - (int) layout.getLineLeft(i);
                    textRect.right = maxWidth;
                }
                textRect.offsetTo(0, 0);
                if (availableSPace.contains(textRect))
                    // may be too small, don't worry we will find the best match
                    return -1;
                // else, too big
                return 1;
            }
        };
        _initialized = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAllCaps(boolean allCaps) {
        super.setAllCaps(allCaps);
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(final Typeface tf) {
        super.setTypeface(tf);
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(final float size) {
        _maxTextSize = size;
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(final int maxlines) {
        super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
        _maxLines = maxlines;
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxLines() {
        return _maxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine() {
        super.setSingleLine();
        _maxLines = 1;
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine(final boolean singleLine) {
        super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
        if (singleLine)
            _maxLines = 1;
        else _maxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLines(final int lines) {
        super.setLines(lines);
        _maxLines = lines;
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(final int unit, final float size) {
        final Context c = getContext();
        Resources r;
        if (c == null)
            r = Resources.getSystem();
        else r = c.getResources();
        _maxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(final float add, final float mult) {
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
        _spacingMult = mult;
        _spacingAdd = add;
    }

    /**
     * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
     *
     * @param minTextSize
     */
    public void setMinTextSize(final float minTextSize) {
        _minTextSize = minTextSize;
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    private void adjustTextSize() {
        // This is a workaround for truncated text issue on ListView, as shown here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView/pull/14
        // TODO think of a nicer, elegant solution.
//    post(new Runnable()
//    {
//    @Override
//    public void run()
//      {
        if (!_initialized)
            return;
        final int startSize = (int) _minTextSize;
        final int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom() - getCompoundPaddingTop();
        _widthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
        if (_widthLimit <= 0)
            return;
        _paint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
        _availableSpaceRect.right = _widthLimit;
        _availableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;
        superSetTextSize(startSize);
//      }
//    });
    }

    private void superSetTextSize(int startSize) {
        int textSize = binarySearch(startSize, (int) _maxTextSize, _sizeTester, _availableSpaceRect);
        super.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    }

    private int binarySearch(final int start, final int end, final SizeTester sizeTester, final RectF availableSpace) {
        int lastBest = start, lo = start, hi = end - 1, mid;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = lo + hi >>> 1;
            final int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);
            if (midValCmp < 0) {
                lastBest = lo;
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else if (midValCmp > 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;
                lastBest = hi;
            } else return mid;
        }
        // make sure to return last best
        // this is what should always be returned
        return lastBest;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before, final int after) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
        adjustTextSize();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int width, final int height, final int oldwidth, final int oldheight) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
        if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight)
            adjustTextSize();
    }
}
```

### The question

Why does it occur? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you want to show the text to the end then make the width of TextView as match_parent

Comment: That's not what I asked about. I asked about what's wrong in the algorithm, that changes the font size according to the size of the TextView (as well as other things). Setting the width of the TextView to match_parent won't help, because the container can be of the size that's problematic. You are talking about whoever uses the library I've made, not about the library's bug itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's possible using support library:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#f00"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced" android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
        android:text="This is an example text" android:textSize="30dp" app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

Sadly, it has 2 disadvantages:

1. Doesn't always spread words nicely. Reported [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79936443).
2. Requires Android API 23 and above ([**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setBreakStrategy(int))).

More information [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356787/878126).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in my project. Long-time Googling, StackOverflow (with your question among others). Nothing.

And my final "solution" was `BreakIterator` for words + measure them all to check this situation.

**UPDATE (2018-08-10):**

```
static public boolean isTextFitWidth(final @Nullable String source, final @NonNull BreakIterator bi, final @NonNull TextPaint paint, final int width, final float textSize)
{
    if (null == source || source.length() <= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    TextPaint paintCopy = new TextPaint();
    paintCopy.set(paint);
    paintCopy.setTextSize(textSize);

    bi.setText(source);
    int start = bi.first();
    for (int end = bi.next(); BreakIterator.DONE != end; start = end, end = bi.next()) {
        int wordWidth = (int)Math.ceil(paintCopy.measureText(source, start, end));
        if (wordWidth > width) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static public boolean isTextFitWidth(final @NonNull TextView textView, final @NonNull BreakIterator bi, final int width, final @Nullable Float textSize)
{
    final int textWidth = width - textView.getPaddingLeft() - textView.getPaddingRight();
    return isTextFitWidth(textView.getText().toString(), bi, textView.getPaint(), textWidth,
            null != textSize ? textSize : textView.getTextSize());
}
```

Comment: I think it needs some more work, to be used within the TextView itself, so that it will take all TextView properties into consideration. But the idea seems ok. You probably try multiple tests till it fits the width, right? But how do you use `BreakIterator` ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper in fact I wanted to show you the final component, but it was developed under NDA and I was disallowed to publish it...  In my implementation I subclassed TextView, created `BreakIterator` with `BreakIterator.getWordInstance()` as final private property and passed to methods from answer above. And yep, to get final size I do multiple tests similar to Quicksort algorithm and measuring text each time. I do it on each `onDraw` tick but with necessity check (size or text/hint when there is no text should be changed).

Comment: So this code isn't enough sadly. It misses a very important part to make it work...