# Android autosizing TextViews split up words before decreasing font size

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, autosize

Is there a way to avoid it?

If my text is "Blablabla" and it doesn't fit in a square, I don't want to have something like:

`Blabla-
  bla`

I want "Blablabla" with a smaller font size. Is there a way to control whether the autosizing TextView will split up words or not?

Here's an example of the issue:

[image]

The minimum text size there is `1sp`, so it's pretty clear the word could fit with a decreased text size.

It seems this has been reported:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38468964

Comment: Maybe you can get your `TextView`'s line count programmatically. If it is greater than 1, just decrease text size and control again.

Comment: @CagriYalcin I want to still break lines when appropriate, though (e.g. if there are two separate words, like "Bla Bla", it'd be ok to have one "Bla" on top of the other). I just don't want to split words.

Comment: Android Studio already splits words when the text filled the line without '-'. I think i'm missing some important points in your question.

Comment: What do you mean with Android Studio? Autosizing TextViews decreases the size of the text automatically so it fits my square, right? The issue is, instead of decreasing "Blablabla" until it fits in one line (because it would fit with a smaller font size), it splits the word so it fits with a larger font size, since there's space available in the square. The point is: if there's space below/above the text, then Android will split up the word first before decreasing the font size to make it fit. It's ok to break lines between words, but splitting words is messed up IMHO.

Comment: No, text size does not decrease. If you set it's width to `wrap_content`, it increases it's width automatically. When it reaches like `match_parent`, it moves the last word to another line.

Comment: At the same time, if you set looong text as one word. it will overflow and you will see your text with some loss.

Comment: @CagriYalcin It does decrease. You're probably thinking about the default behavior of TextViews, while I'm talking about the new autosizing TextViews https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html#setting-textview-autosize

Comment: Oh, seems i was wrong. Thanks for information that i don't know about.

Comment: I have the same problem, @ThiagoPorciúncula have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @AmeyaB No :( best we can do is star that issue, spread the word and hope for the best. I don't see any way we could fix that ourselves.

Answer (score 6):

I've actually reported about this issue in the past ([**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38468964) and [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68787108), one you've already found out about), but it seems there is a solution, or at least it seems to work for me.

I think the tip could help:

[image]

- https://youtu.be/x-FcOX6ErdI?t=218
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setBreakStrategy(int)

This means you can choose the break strategy for the textView. Example:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="250dp" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:background="#f00"
   android:breakStrategy="balanced" 
   android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
   android:text="This is an example text" 
   android:textSize="30dp" 
   app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

Sadly, this doesn't always seem to work nicely as it should. I've noticed that on Hebrew, it sometimes doesn't get spread well:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79936443

But at least it won't put part-words for no reason.

The major disadvantage of using this solution, is that it's available only from API 23 (at least 62% of the devices, according to [**Android dashboard statistics**](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/)). Someone has asked it to be on the support library ([**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37087755)), but was told it's impossible.

Comment: So you're saying that we can fix this (at least for English) by simply adding `android:breakStrategy="balanced"` and `android:hyphenationFrequency="none"`? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @FredPorciúncula I've tested it on supported devices, and it works fine. Where have you tested? Can you please share a sample project to show the issue you are having?

Comment: Sure! I've tested on a Nexus 5X emulator and on a Pixel 3 device, both running API 28. I can reproduce the issue with the code on my original question. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/tfcporciuncula/cc3e7479e664c9c3d77d88d79d3da8ff

If you look at the preview you can see the issue right away. It's like whenever there's vertical space, Android will decide to split up the word and break the line no matter what (instead of simply decreasing the font size). If you keep increasing the string, the font will decrease at some point, but only when there's no more vertical space available.

Comment: @FredPorciúncula Odd. Was sure it worked fine now. You can try my old solution then, here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView . Maybe I've even reported about the issue you wrote: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68787108 .

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found a "precarious" work around. For me it works because the text I needed to put in the textView was only one or two words... Anyway, I hope it helps or, at least, it gives you some inspiration.
Here's what i did:

in XML I added `android:maxLines="2"` to the AppCompatTextView.

in code I checked if the text was only ONE word and, if so, set programmatically `textView.setMaxLines(1);`

I understand it not a perfect nor a universal solution but was good enough for me.
Anyway... if you only need to scale "Blablabla" properly using `android:maxLines="1"` should do the trick.

Comment: That's interesting! One can definitely fix this issue for simple cases by playing around with `maxLines` as you did.

Answer (score 1):

I came here having the same issues with two-line text as others. The only thing that works for me is this: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView

It's not as convenient as adding a couple lines to your layout, but it works in situations where Android's auto size doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this gives someone a better idea.

Basically, we force AutoSizing feature to use a single line to measure the text, so it will be forced to use minimum text size.

Then after the measure is done, we allow it to use more lines if it needs.

```
public static void setTextForAutoSizingUsingMinimumLines(final TextView textView, final String text) {
textView.setMaxLines(1);
textView.setText(text);

textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
        if (layout == null) {
            return;
        }

        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        if (layout.getLineCount() > textView.getMaxLines()) {
            //Let TextView use as much lines Layout needs to display text.
            textView.setMaxLines(layout.getLineCount());
            textView.invalidate();
        }
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a button with Android autotextsizing the string "Reading lists" over two lines as "Readin" and "g lists".

The only successful workaround I could find was to replace the blank space between the words with a line-feed ("\n").  So the string resource became:

```
<string name="textButtonReadingLists">Reading\nlists</string>
```

Not ideal, but Android put "Reading" on one line and "lists" below it.  Hope that helps someone else.